# Isn't this comma splices?

Tags: grammar

I found this on the page " word of the day; yom tov" on dictionary.com

"I know it's yom tov, I know he must be celebrating his own seder with his family."
(Irwin Wolfe, Goodbye Beaver Lake, 2001)

How is this different from comma splices? I think that comma alone is connecting two independent clauses.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: There's no dispensation for yom tov.  It's a comma splice, but sometimes authors of fiction take liberties with punctuation to mimic conversation.

Comment: This use of comma has been a question to me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do people post comments in this forum as opposed to answering the questions directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly a comma splice. "I know..." and "I know..." Two independent clauses joined with a comma. But I agree with previous poster about fiction mimicking speech.